# how to detect a swipe triggered on a view after it's long pressed in android

Tags: android, view, keyboard, swipe, detect

I want to display two buttons after one button is long pressed and achieve their selection via user's swipe to up/left direction without giving in a second touch event.

I tried GestureDetector onLongPress to show buttons and then: 
onFling-> user needs to provide a fling action to achieve selection. Not desired behaviour (in android keyboard key, user can select option without lifting his finger)
onScroll-> I can't get the ACTION_UP. And, user needs to touch twice.

how to detect a swipe triggered on a view after it's being long pressed in android (single touch event) e.g. it's done for a keyboard (9-key format) key?

I need to do:
action_1 on normal click
action_2 on long click (showing buttons) and checking their selection by swipe in single touch event of long click

Please help..!

Comment: you can use onTouch event, and ACTION_DOWN, ACTIOU_MOVE event types. So basically you save time of ACTION_DOWN, and check for ACTION_UP not happend during some time(long click), and after that you detect a swipe using ACTION_MOVE

Comment: can you share the code for this? i need to also differentiate between normal click, long click and swipe.... in short, click -> action1, long click -> action2 + swipe detection and selection in single touch event...

Comment: I don't have the code. It would take some time to write it, but I gave the idea how to do it. You can write code by yourself

Comment: @VladMatvienko bro, i'm quite not getting the separation part of these events...it will be quite helpful if you could share the code to support..!